# get absolute url on handle ressource request on blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me, absolute-path, browserfield

I use this method the get the urls of ressources contain on web page

```
public InputConnection handleResourceRequest(BrowserFieldRequest request) throws Exception 
{
    final String url = request.getURL();
    return super.handleResourceRequest(request);
}
```

But, I made `request.getURL();` it returns relative url and not the absolute url.

How can I change it to get the absolute URL?

Comment: I tested with this code, and **did** get absolute URLs from `request.getURL()`.  If my suggestion below doesn't help, can you tell us which device and OS version you're running on?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When I run your code, it **does** return me absolute URLs, even when my web page contained *relative* links.  That said, it wouldn't surprise me if sometimes, it doesn't.  I haven't fully tested this code, but I would think you could try something like this.

Basically, you check to see if the URL is absolute, and if not, you assemble an absolute URL by using the parent `BrowserField` document URL:

```
  ProtocolController controller = new ProtocolController(_browserField) {

     public InputConnection handleResourceRequest(BrowserFieldRequest request) throws Exception {
        String absoluteUrl = null;
        URI uri = URI.create(request.getURL());
        if (uri.isAbsolute()) {
           absoluteUrl = request.getURL();
        } else {
           String docUrl = _browserField.getDocumentUrl();
           String url = request.getURL();
           if (url.startsWith("/")) {
              // the URL is relative to the server root
              URI docUri = URI.create(docUrl);
              absoluteUrl = docUri.getScheme() + "://" + docUri.getHost() + url;
           } else {
              // the URL is relative to the document URL
              absoluteUrl = docUrl + url;
           }
        }
        System.out.println("   requesting: " + absoluteUrl);
        return super.handleResourceRequest(request);
     }
  }
```

Again, for me, I was getting absolute URLs, so I couldn't easily test the code in the branch where the URL is relative.  So, it's possible that I'm dropping a `"/"` somewhere, or not handling `file:///` URLs properly.

But, this is a starting point, to workaround your problem.